# What is the perspective of the western buddhist cannon websites?

Tags: pali-canon

In the eastern perspective, Tipitaka is memorized and studied by Atthakatha-teachers from generation to generation and still going on nowadays, so it is weird to study Tipitaka without Atthakatha.

But I look at the western Buddhist canon website and they look like "these words are from his disciple's mouth, but I don't want to hear his disciple's explanation because it's not actually his."

For the example, https://suttacentral.net/ protects [84000.org](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/r.php?B=12&A=1&eng=suttacentral) to show suttacentral's page on its iframe directly after this function opened ere long.

I requested this function to 84000.org webmaster because I need to use tipitaka, atthakatha, and tika in pali thai, pali roman, siamrattha thai translation, mahamakutta thai university translation, MCU translation, and **english translation**. (I don't know why 84000.org chose iframe instead of the real source from inside, but I think the webmaster may avoid the license problem).

Actually, that protection is not the main idea, however it means suttacentral webmasters already knew the problem that suttacentral has not enough canons for the reference, no Atthakatha-pali and no Tika. It's ok for that protection, but it makes the questions that why don't suttacentral and the other western buddhist canon websites put the losing resources into their website, although they already knew there were demands?

So,

1. What is the perspective of the western Buddhist canon website to protect the Buddhist people from Atthakatha study?
2. Why the western Buddhist canon website acts like  "these words are from his disciple's mouth, but I don't want to hear his disciple's explanation because it's not actually his"?

Another, why don't the western Buddhist canon websites make the function for easier reference such as [highlight function](http://www.84000.org/tipitaka/read/roman_read.php?B=12&A=1&h=Nevasa%C3%B1%C3%B1%C4%81n%C4%81sa#hl)?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/96966/discussion-on-question-by-bonn-what-is-the-perspective-of-the-western-buddhist-c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **OP:** It's ok for that protection, but it makes the questions that why don't suttacentral and the other western buddhist canon websites
>   put the losing resources into their website, although they already
>   knew there were demands?
>
> **OP:** Another, why don't the western Buddhist canon websites make the function for easier reference such as highlight function?

SuttaCentral for example, has a discussion forum [here](https://discourse.suttacentral.net/). If you want new features. You can ask them directly. I'm sure other "western" buddhist canon websites have similarly reachable community or administrators. If they lack manpower, maybe they will focus on the canon first, which is itself huge.

Apart from the suttas, there's also translation of the Visuddhimagga online and also summaries of the Abhidhamma.

> **OP:** What is the perspective of the western Buddhist canon website to protect the Buddhist people from Atthakatha study?

I think this is largely due a lack of manpower, so they focus on what they think people need the most.

For example, you can see that not all of the Sutta Pitaka is available on AccessToInsight. Only the ones judged by the admin to be the most useful are there. Similarly with Piya Tan's collection at The Minding Centre.

On the other hand, SuttaCentral has grown to contain a far bigger collection of the suttas, perhaps hoping to cover the whole Sutta Pitaka one day. This is by itself a huge effort.

Comparatively, the Atthakatha is seen as secondary to the Suttas and less important.

But nevertheless you can read parts of the Atthakatha indirectly quoted by Piya Tan at The Minding Centre and other translators like Thanissaro Bhikkhu on AccessToInsight.

> **OP:** Why the western Buddhist canon website acts like "these words are from his disciple's mouth, but I don't want to hear his disciple's
>   explanation because it's not actually his"?

I don't think this is the attitude. I think it's more like "*I want to listen to the master's words first. That's more important to me. But if there is a disciple explaining it, I can refer to it, but it's less important or secondary.*"

Comment: Almost all Buddhist sects orally recited&memorized tipitaka for at least 145+ years, so all of Buddhist canons are secondary because all of them come from the disciples' mouth, right? 

I understand you and the good mind of the webmasters and I know how hard it is to maintain a website, but the dhamma looks like downgrade when I add a link from 84000.org, however I have no other choices to use. The link is very important for the readers because if I don't make a link, it is my fault when the reader doesn't understand what I written, but I do my best by the link. And they don't like quotation

Answer (score 0):

I think it's almost the same question as to why some people reject Mahayana, which is the teaching passed by students of Buddha, just like Atthakatha.

Or why some people reject Visuddhimagga.

Or why some people reject Abhidharma.

I guess some people just don't trust anything expect The Canon.

And why do they not trust it? I think, it's because they don't really understand Dharma, so they can't see for themselves which teaching is correct and which is not. Because they can't see the deep meaning and can't understand connection of topics to one another and to real life. So they don't have any way of knowing which teaching to trust - which leaves them with nothing but The Canon.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to say something extremely important. It leads to a sort of scriptural dogmatism and divides Buddhism (or whichever 'ism' it happens to be) from the rest of mysticism and even sometimes from major areas of Buddhist teaching. I appreciate that this is probably a touchy topic.  .  .

Comment: I think I put this question in the canon section, not practice. Some practitioner often shows their ego over the canon-keeper, but both of them come together in Buddhist culture, nothing is better. In the canon section, the justice of canon comes from the evidence, history, and witness. **No trust. It's same in the cort, archeology, etc.** The trust and judgement comes after the consideration of the fact from  the evidence, history, and witness. What whe western website doing, in my eyes, is hidding   the evidence, history, and witness from the students and the practitioners.

Answer (score -1):

> **Q. Why the western Buddhist canon website acts like "these words are from his disciple's mouth, but I don't want to hear his disciple's
>   explanation because it's not actually his"?**

A Western Buddhist website is https://www.accesstoinsight.org. On this website is the *Ani Sutta: The Peg SN 20.7*, where the Lord Buddha told us to not follow the "**words of disciples**", as follows:

> In the course of the future there will be monks who won't listen when
>   discourses that are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their
>   meaning, transcendent, connected with emptiness — are being recited.
>   They won't lend ear, won't set their hearts on knowing them, won't
>   regard these teachings as worth grasping or mastering. But they will
>   listen when discourses that are literary works — the works of poets,
>   elegant in sound, elegant in rhetoric, the work of outsiders, **words of
>   disciples** — are recited. They will lend ear and set their hearts on
>   knowing them. They will regard these teachings as worth grasping &
>   mastering.
>
> In this way the disappearance of the discourses that are words of the
>   Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning, transcendent, connected with
>   emptiness — will come about.
>
> Thus you should train yourselves: 'We will listen when discourses that
>   are words of the Tathagata — deep, deep in their meaning,
>   transcendent, connected with emptiness — are being recited. We will
>   lend ear, will set our hearts on knowing them, will regard these
>   teachings as worth grasping & mastering.' That's how you should train
>   yourselves.

Aṭṭhakathā (Pali for explanation, commentary) refers to Pali-language Theravadin Buddhist commentaries to the canonical Theravadin Tipitaka.

**Aṭṭhakathā** is the **words of** (heretic) **disciples** (with wrong view).

Aṭṭhakathā leads to 'rebirth' in the 'animal kingdom' and, eventually, to 'hell'.

Some examples of 'rebirth' in the fire of 'hell' is below:

[image]
 [image]

[image][image]
[image][image]

Comment: You're answering that "Aṭṭhakathā is wrong view" is "the perspective of the western buddhist cannon websites"? Which cannon websites is that true of -- is there evidence that the authors or editors of those websites have that view?

Comment: This website for starters: https://dhammadhatu.wordpress.com/ and any other website I posted on. Kind regards

Comment: I don't think this is an answer -- it implies that the "perspective of western canon websites" is defined or motivated by your own opinion (assuming that what you posted is your own opinion). The OP asked about "canon websites", I think that means the sites which collect and publish (translated) anthologies of the canon, i.e. suttacentral and so on -- not blogs and forums and so on.

Comment: I have Right View.